# how to order by likes.count in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i have FQL something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id=PAGEID
ORDER BY likes.count desc
LIMIT 5
```

but how can i achieve similar with facebook graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: This is currently not possible. You only could sort in your applciation after retrieving all results.

Comment: thanx tobi, now have opt an alternate way